# Debugger error: not in executable format: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, gdb

I've written a program, saved it on the desktop under the name '`Swap.cpp`' and when I run gdb (the first time), I get the error:

> "/Users/*myname*/Desktop/Swap": not in executable format: File format
>   not recognized.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Sorry I should've given more information:

> I am using Mac OS.
>   I've already compiled the program and have the Swap.o file that I can see on my desktop.And here are the commands that I enter while trying to run the debugger from bash:

```
    $ clang++ -g Swap.cpp -o Swap
    $ ./Swap
```

this runs Swap and then I try to access the debugger using:

```
    $ gdb Swap
```

that then gives me the aforesaid message. I tried doing what Rakholiya Jenish suggested but to no avail.

Comment: how did you compile this file?

Comment: or, more to the point, *did you compile this file* ?

Comment: Please state which OS you are using, Windows or Mac OS X

Comment: Can you show us the output of `file ./Swap` and `gdb --version|head -1` ?

Answer (score 0):

To run gdb on windows:

```
path_to_gdb.exe program_to_debug
```

If the compilation was not proper, either compile it with your IDE (if you are using) or with g++ using `cmd.exe` as:

```
 g++ -g Swap.cpp -o output -lm
```

Comment: Looks to me as though OP is running Windows. `chmod` won't work

Comment: @Levi  `/Users/username/Desktop` is more characteristic of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured out how to use lldb instead of gdb. lldb works just fine. Here is what I did:

```
    $ clang++ -g -o Swap Swap.cpp
    $ lldb Swap
```

> Thank you all for your help.